# How to change the permissions of multiple liferay articles

Tags: permissions, liferay, article, webcontent

The website I am working on has 600 articles and all of them have the view permission off for guest.

Is there any easy way to change the permission for all web content to view for guest users? I really would like to avoid having to manually change each article if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set VIEW permission for Guest role for all journal articles (even for future ones).

Go to <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Roles</kbd>  → <kbd>Guest</kbd>  → <kbd>Define permissions</kbd> and in `Add permissions` select box select Site content: Web content. Then choose View permission in Web content section and save. Now all web contents (journal articles) will be visible to guest users.

OR

You can also write a short script to programatically set VIEW permissions to all the web-contents created till now.